# DCC Error E2597 ld: library not found for -lbz2

Tags: delphi

I am trying to compile one blank Delphi project targeting iOS Device 32/64 but getting this error

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: library not found for -lbz2
[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

My environment is Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3, MacOSX 10.13.5, XCode 9.4.1, iOS 11.4, iPhone 6s. On my project it's totally blank without any code just default Form. I also installed iOS 11.3 patch. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you delete the iOS 11.4 SDK from SDK Manager, then re-add it, then do a build?

Comment: Can you also provide what appears in the "Output" tab? The last few lines may be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new vmware workstation and install Delphi Tokyo there. The issue is 3rd Party component's library path. On the newly installed Delphi Tokyo on vmware I didn't install any 3rd Party component. It did deploy my app to my iPhone. After that followed vmware Delphi's library path to my host(main) Delphi Library path and edit as per vmware Delphi's library path. On my main Delphi I have trial XtremeDocumentStudio Delphi, Winsoft PDFium Component Suite which causes the problem.